# php regex pattern help -

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to wrap my head around regex, but would appreciate some help on this.

The given string is `"38min *08min 38 *08min 36 *01min *26 50 *15min *41 *11min *41"`

Trying to parse this string in PHP so that:

```
arr[0] = "38"
arr[1] = "08,38"
arr[2] = "08, 36"
arr[3] = "01, 26, 50"
arr[4] = "15, 41"
arr[5] = "11, 41"
```

I need an output something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `*` delimiters seemingly are incoherent, I would use an awfully complex regex for that:

```
preg_match_all('#
        (\d+)min[\s*]+
        (?:
            (\d+)(?!min|\d)
                (?:
                   [\s*]+(\d+)(?!min|\d)
                )?
        )?#x',
        $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 38min *
            [1] => 38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08min 38
            [1] => 08
            [2] => 38
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08min 36
            [1] => 08
            [2] => 36
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01min *26 50
            [1] => 01
            [2] => 26
            [3] => 50
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15min *41
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 41
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11min *41
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 41
        )

)
```

You'll have to reassemble the [1] and [2] and [3] entries for your wanted strings.

Comment: Thanks Mario
I get the following output:


Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 38min * [1] => 38 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 08min 38 [1] => 08 [2] => 38 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08min 36 [1] => 08 [2] => 36 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 01min *26 50 [1] => 01 [2] => 26 [3] => 50 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 15min *41 [1] => 15 [2] => 41 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 11min *41 [1] => 11 [2] => 41 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 11min *41 [1] => 11 [2] => 41 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 11min *41 [1] => 11 [2] => 41 ) [8] => Array \...

And it keeps going.


But I'll try work with it and what you gave.

Thanks

Comment: That looks okay. You can use `foreach ($match as $row) { array_shift($row); echo implode(", ", $row), "\n"; }` to get your desired output I believe.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "38min *08min 38 *08min 36 *01min *26 50 *15min *41 *11min *41";
$parts = split('*', $str);

$result = array();
foreach ($parts as $part) {
  $result[] = trim(str_replace('min', ', ', $part));
}
```

This isn't really a regex issue imo but that code should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
$arr = explode($inStr, '*');
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i += 1) {
    $arr[$i] = str_replace('min', ',', $arr[$i]);
}
```

Where your data is in `$instr`.